# Ajax Get Request works fine when requested in browser, but gets 302 in iframe. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I am working on a web app that makes several ajax requests at startup. The applications works fine when ran individually, in the browser.

When running it into a iframe, one of the ajax requests returns a 302 Found HTTP status. I'm sure I'm hitting the same url with both the browser and the iframe.

The application that creates the frame is on a different domain and port.

What could be causing this? Out of 5 get requests to the same server, only one (the third) gets a 302.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The application that creates the frame is on a different domain and port.

That's why. You're making a cross-domain AJAX request which isn't allowed without special considerations.

You need to set up CORS on the server-side to allow this. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Comment: What eludes me is why the other requests from frame application work. They hit the same server API as the one that fails.

Comment: Maybe some parts of the API set up CORS rules and some don't? You can see where this is the case though by looking at the response headers.

Comment: Will look into that and come back with an answer. Thanks.

Comment: The problem was with an extra header that was sent from the frame. I guess you're quite close to the best answer. Thanks.